# htop shows >100% for a single-threaded application

Tags: multithreading, cpu-usage, htop

I have haproxy 1.7.2 running on CentOS7 with two hexacore CPUs. haproxy runs with default setting of `nbproc=1`. Here is output of htop:

[image]

How can a single-threaded application utilize more than 100% of CPU? `top` or `atop` never show >100% CPU utilization for that process.